# Decrease spam rate for a domain in gmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, amazon-ses

I am sending emails from my website with postfix my domain name. But suddenly my email credentials was compromised and someone used my credentials to send thousands of emails to peoples. So Because of that, peoples mark that email as SPAM.

> Because of that, Now emails are **coming to spam in GMAIL** now.

Please tell me, How can i fix that issue.

Note: I am using aws ses email service.

Comment: Do you have DKIM and SPF records set up for your domain?  That will help but it will take time for the spam reports to time out.

Comment: Rajat were you able to solve this issue? I have the same

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to have proper SPF + DKIM + DMARC set in your domain, other than that, you can do everything good, but there is 0 guarantee that your email will never be marked as spam, sadly, it's half in your control, the other half is what others have reported from your domain, your server, your content, your actual username, links included, etc. Keep in mind that your reputaion varies per server, so if emails land in spam in Gmail, it doesn't necesarily mean that it'll land in spam in hotmail. Sometimes using a completely different domain/server/service helps, but if the reputation is already tainted, only marking emails as 'not spam' would eventually help the delivery (I know, it sucks when that happens).

Comment: I dont know what you are saying. Can you please explain?

Comment: Do a web search on the terms SPF, DKIM, DMARC.